# How to write an application to CDC class type USB driver

Tags: linux, usb, driver

I am new to device driver programming. My objective is to write an application ,on Linux platform, to access contents of USB CDC class type device through PC.

So with baby steps, I firstly wanna simulate an environment such that a CDC type USB takes command(s) from host PC and then transfers data to that host after acknowledging those command(s).

I have googled extensively but I am missing something since I have not been able to understand much from the limited explanations I have obtained.

So can u suggest me a correct approach? or some handy URLs which can explain how to write user applications to CDC type USB better?

Thank you.
-Sai

Comment: CDC emulates simply com-port, so, work with it is quite simple! First you can try something like `com` from `tinyserial` package.

Comment: thank u @Eddy_Em. Since I am new, i dont understand wat did u mean in ur answer..If u could elaborate it a little, i would be grateful.

Comment: Well, I can't give you a full answer because of little information in your question: how do you wanna do CDC? For example, you can find a ready CDC example for STM32 microcontroller. I did such thing and wrote a little but [in russian](http://eddy-em.livejournal.com/29851.html).

Comment: What is this CDC refering to? Most users of this tag use is for Database relates Change Data Capture. SQL stuff. Is that your intend also?

Comment: @Eddy_em: i wanna connect my desktop to a TMS320DM365. The PC gives commands to the muC & accepts data in the form of images from the muC. I only need to know to write a code which can open the USB, send commands and accepts data. Is this explanation sufficient? Thank You.

Comment: If this is a real CDC, you don't need to know how to open USB device: real CDC emulates an USB-com, so just open `/dev/tyACM0` and work with is like with simple com port!

Comment: ah... "Communication Device Class". The other 99 topics with this tag refer to "Change Data Capture", so you may want to drop the CDC tag for this topic. Thanks.

Comment: ok @Hein, I have dropped CDC tag to remove ambiguity.